# To check the values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

```
def pricemonitor(x):
    global cheap_cheap
    asyncio.run(searching(x))
    df1 = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\N\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\Scrapped results\\" + x + ".xlsx")

    cheap_data = {
        "Item Name": "Empty",
        "New Price": "Empty",
        "Old Price": "Empty",
        "Amount difference": "Empty"
    }

    for x in df["Item Name"]:
        if df1["Item Name"].str.contains(x):
                if df["Item Price"] != "Not Available" and df["Discounted Price"] != "Not Available" and df1["Item Price"] != "Not Available" and df1["Discounted Price"] != "Not Available":
                    cheaper = pricecompare(df["Discounted Price"],df1["Discounted Price"])
                    if cheaper < 0:
                        cheap_data["Item Name"] = df["ItemName"]
                        cheap_data["New Price"] = df["Discounted Price"]
                        cheap_data["old Price"] = df1["Discounted Price"]
                        cheap_data["Amount difference"] = cheaper
                        df1["Discounted Price"] = df["Discounted Price"]
                    else:
                        pass

                elif df["Item Price"] != "Not Available" and df1["Item Price"] != "Not Available":
                    cheaper = pricecompare(df["Item Price"], df1["Item Price"])
                    if cheaper < 0:
                        cheap_data["Item Name"] = df["ItemName"]
                        cheap_data["New Price"] = df["Item Price"]
                        cheap_data["old Price"] = df1["Item Price"]
                        cheap_data["Amount difference"] = cheaper
                        df1["Item Price"] = df["Item Price"]
                    else:
                        pass

                elif df["Discounted Price"] != "Not Available" and df1["Discounted Price"] != "Not Available":
                    cheaper = pricecompare(df["Discounted Price"], df1["Discounted Price"])
                    if cheaper < 0:
                        cheap_data["Item Name"] = df["ItemName"]
                        cheap_data["New Price"] = df["Discounted Price"]
                        cheap_data["old Price"] = df1["Discounted Price"]
                        cheap_data["Amount difference"] = cheaper
                        df1["Discounted Price"] = df["Discounted Price"]
                    else:
                        pass

                else:
                    pass

                cheap_cheap = df.append(pd.DataFrame(cheap_data, index=[0]), ignore_index=True)
```

My current intention is to compare the dataframe I have just scraped with the dataframe converted from my excel sheet by their name and if the name teles with one another I would replace the values and do some calculations with the information obtained.

But currently `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` this was the error I encountered.

Upon my research I understand that my current code gives a number of true and false which cause the current state to be ambiguous and I understand that one of the ways to solve this was to do something like this `df[df1["Item Name"] == x]` but this doesn't fit my current intention.

Is there any methods which would allow me to locate if df1 contains the same name as df then perform whatever data analytics it needs to

Comment: Replace and with & in your if statements

Comment: can't as there is a string class there hence it cannot be defined

Comment: You need to wrap your conditions inside ( ) these brackets and use & operator between consitions

Comment: nope doesn't work causes the same error